# Feature SQL Server 2012 - Filetable - The location of the file can not be opened

Tags: sql-server-2012, filestream, filetable

When trying to access the files available on the virtual directory created for FileTable, you receive the following error message:

> "The location of the file can not be opened. Access is not enabled or not you have the permissions for it."

Already granted all permissions, however, the application displays this error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have

> "Allow remote clients access to FILESTREAM data"  selected  as shown below :

[image]

Also, you need to leave the windows share as a Globalroot path and manage permissions through table properties, not Windows share properties.

Refer to : [Prerequisites for FileTable](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509097.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
But this configuration has been applied and the error persists.

Comment: @CamilaReis How are you managing permissions - table properties or windows share ?

Comment: Table properties. Granted access to the application user to the table. My biggest problem is that this error is reflecting in my application, because when trying to access through the application server, error access denied.

Comment: A profiler should show you why it is throws error from application .. Permission issue.

Comment: Solve remote access as follows.
1. Associate the user of the application pool to the database instance.
2. Grant access to insert, edit, delete, and update data FileTable.
IMPORTANT: in our case such access had to be granted through scripting when grant this access via the configuration screen of the user, access was not allowed. (We do not know why)

However, for an access of FileTable has not been possible. Apparently it is corrupted. Has anyone experienced this situation? I can not even delete it to create it again.